# How to ADB "reboot download" in bash script?

Tags: bash, adb, command-line-arguments

I would like to reboot many Android devices to download mode simultaneously.

Both of the following work from the command line:

```
    adb reboot
    adb reboot download
```

The following bash script also works:

```
adb devices | while read line
do
    if [ ! "$line" = "" ] && [ `echo $line | awk '{print $2}'` = "device" ]
    then
        device=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
        echo "$device $@ ..."
        adb -s $device "reboot" &
    fi
done
```

However, when I replace 'reboot' with 'reboot download', the script only provides ADB usage instructions:

```
user@user /home 
$ ./rebootToDownload.bsh 
29f7654c  ...

user@user /home 
$ Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31

 -a                            - directs adb to listen on all interfaces for a connection
 -d                            - directs command to the only connected USB device
                                 returns an error if more than one USB device is present.
 -e                            - directs command to the only running emulator.
 ...
```

Could someone please explain why 'ADB reboot' executes successfully, but not 'ADB reboot download'?

Is there any way around this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: drop the quotes around your `reboot download`

Comment: That was it. Thanks again Alex.